# Cell's progress bar duplicates on other cells

Tags: ios, progress-bar, uitableview, reuseidentifier

I have a cell reuse problem.

All my cells are identical, there is only one section. Cells include a label, button and progress bar.

The button triggers a sound (it's a simple "play" button). When the AVAudioPlayers delegate method is called, `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:`, I nullify the `NSTimer` that updates the progress bar, hide the progress bar, and nullify the audio player as well.

All this happens in my cell's class which inherites from `UITableViewCell`.

Everything works like it should, except for one thing :

**Scrolling while playing a sound shows the same progress bar on the new cells.**

So if I tap, say, the second cell, the second next cell being shown when scrolling will have a progress bar moving forward (and stop+hide when the sound finishes).

I'll show you my custom cell complete class, I hope this will help. I don't really know how to fix this. I tried if-statements in the `cellForRow:` but without any real success.

```
@implementation SoundItemTableViewCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    // Initialization code
    self.progressBar.hidden = YES;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

- (IBAction)playSound:(id)sender {

    [self.progressBar setProgress:0];
    self.progressBar.hidden = NO;

    NSString *filename = self.fileName;
    [self playSoundWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:filename]];
}

- (void)playSoundWithURL:(NSURL*)url{


    NSError *error;
    if (self.audioPlayer){

        if(self.audioPlayer.playing){
            [self.audioPlayer stop];
        }
    }

    self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    self.audioPlayer.delegate = self;
    self.tmrProgress = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1f target:self selector:@selector(updateElapsedTime) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    [self.audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [self.audioPlayer play];
    NSLog(@"Starting sound play with item : %@",url);

}

- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag{

    [self.progressBar setProgress:0 animated:YES];
    self.progressBar.hidden = YES;
    //self.progressBar = nil;
    [self.tmrProgress invalidate];
    self.tmrProgress = nil;
    player = nil;
    self.audioPlayer = nil;
    NSLog(@"Audio Finish");
}


- (void)updateElapsedTime{
    if (self.audioPlayer) {
        NSLog(@"Updating progress");
        [self.progressBar setProgress:[self.audioPlayer currentTime] / [self.audioPlayer duration]];
    }
}
```

The tableview. `pushList` is an array containing file URLs

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *identifier = @"SoundItemTableViewCell";
    SoundItemTableViewCell *cell = [self.tbPushList dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[SoundItemTableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    }
    cell.fileName    = [pushList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.lbName.text = [[[pushList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension];
    return cell;

}
```

The best I could achieve was to hide the progress bar when it goes out of view, and therefore no other progress bar would show either, but rescrolling to my playing cell would then have a sound playing with no progress bar, which is unsatisfactory/bad UX behaviour.

Comment: You should implement prepareForReuse in your cell class and shutdown everything that is nolonger needed. This is called before dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier returns the cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're reusing your audioplayer and surrounding logic. You need something external to check whether the cell in question is the one playing the sound and you need to move the controller logic into the controller.

Add this property to your view controller...

`@property (nonatomic) NSString *playingFilename;`

Move `- (IBAction)playSound:(id)sender` into the view controller and set the string when you select a specific button...

```
- (IBAction)playSound:(id)sender {

    UIButton *playButton = sender;
    NSInteger index = playButton.tag;

    SoundItemTableViewCell *cell = (SoundItemTableViewCell *)[self.tbPushList cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0]];

    [cell.progressBar setProgress:0];
    cell.progressBar.hidden = NO;

    self.playingFilename = [pushList objectAtIndex:index];

    // Personally I'd move the playing logic into the controller as well... spin up as many audio players as you need... but they shouldn't be in the cell.
    [self playSoundWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.playingFileName]];
}
```

then

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *identifier = @"SoundItemTableViewCell";
    SoundItemTableViewCell *cell = [self.tbPushList dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[SoundItemTableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    }


   // tag your button.....
    cell.playButton.tag = indexPath.row;

    cell.lbName.text = [[[pushList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension];

    // check to see if this index contains the right file
   BOOL isRightFile = ([self.playingFilename isEqualToString:[pushList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]])

    cell.progressBar.hidden = !isRightFile;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I had tried that before except for the isRightFile  boolean trick. That's pretty smart let me give it a try :)

Comment: Yep it works. I just have a progress problem when scrolling away and back. The progress bar gets stuck at 100% and doesn't disappear. But I should be able to manage myself :) Thanks Magoo !

Answer (score 4):

Make sure to initialize ALL the properties of your cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.
Since your cells are being recycled, they will keep their existing properties.

Comment: You mean even the audio player and everything? Wouldn't that take a LOT of memory for no potential use?

Comment: No it will take a lot of allocations/deallocations, but that's okay. But the problem is that your audioplayer is part of your cell. You should have only one audioplayer for your whole tableViewController, or you will have troubles to keep the playback going when you scroll.

Comment: Yeah now that I create everything in the cell, the visual behaviour is perfect but like you said, I obviously lose sound when scrolling away from the audio player.
How should I implement only one audio player when the button is on my cell but the URL/player are in the controller?

Comment: You could use the method called by your button to send a notification or to call a tableViewController's method that will start the playback. And then, use the audioplayer's delegate (the tableViewController) to send a notification that your cell will catch to stay aware of the playback state.

Comment: Your answer just saved my life.

Comment: Happy to hear that :')

Comment: @Zil Did you manage to accomplish how to implement just one audio player? I have run into a ditto problem...

Comment: The project got tossed and I don't remember what I chose to do at the time. Sorry man :\

Answer (score 0):

In the table view cell for row method check if the row is selected or not  and if it is not selected then set the progress of progress bar to zero..

Comment: the row is "never" selected, pressing the button inside the cell doesn't select the cell. I have other code running for cell selection